# How does this code find duplicate characters in a string?

Tags: c, duplicates

Example: Given a string (in this example `char *word`) you want to find duplicate characters (bytes).

I wanted to know if someone can explain to me how the following works:

```c
    int table[256] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)  table[word[i]]++;
```

After that you can check with another loop if duplicate or not like:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) if (table[word[i]] > 1) { … }
```

How does this work? I don't understand why duplicated chars are > 1 in the table?

Comment: It counts characters and checks if the count of any character is greater than one.

Comment: Yes I understand that but not how the line: "table[word[i]]++" in the first loop can count the duplicates?

Comment: Go through the program with paper and pen or with the debugger and you will find the answer yourself :)

Comment: It doesn't count duplicates. It counts characters.

Comment: The first loop counts the number of occurrences of each byte value in the range 0..255 (it adds one to the count of the byte for each byte value it finds); the rescan finds the byte values with more than one occurrence in the string — the very definition of a duplicate.  It assumes that the string is a single-byte code set and not UTF-8, for example.  It also assumes that either plain `char` is an unsigned type or that there are no values in the string where `word[i]` is negative.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, this helps. But why does it add to every char value it finds and not to just the one on the current position in the table? When I print out the memory location I see that from an example string "abcda" that both a are the same in memory. I thought in the table array they must be different (but continues) locations, why the is it the same? Maybe this quesiton sounds dumb but I don't understand. Thank you

Comment: When you find `'a'` in a character string, there's a byte value, usually 97, associated with that character.  So when the counting code reads `word[i]` and the content of `word[i]` is `'a'`, it's as if there was 97 in the array (in fact, there is 97 in the array), so the first loop increments `table[97]` — changing it from 0 to 1 when the first `a` in `abcda` is read, and from 1 to 2 when the second `a` is read.  Characters are just numbers, when all is said and done (but there's a heck of a lot of saying and doing that can happen before all is said and done).

Comment: Thank you this clears it up, after thinking about it, it was in fact a "dumb" question :))

Comment: It is not necessary to edit your post to say **Edit** and **Edit2**. There is a [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57750236/revisions) maintained for edits and revisions here. If you feel your question is no longer needed or relevant, you can delete it using the link below the tags at the lower left.

Comment: It wasn't a dumb question; it was a reasonable question because you were stuck.  Once you know the answer, it seems simple, but it wasn't simple until you knew the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring my comments into a semi-coherent answer.*</sup>

The first loop counts the number of occurrences of each byte value in the range 0..255 (it adds one to the count of the byte for each byte value it finds); the rescan finds the byte values with more than one occurrence in the string — the very definition of a duplicate.

The loops both assume that the string is encoded in a single-byte code set and not a multi-byte code set like UTF-8, for example. They also assume that either plain `char` is an unsigned type (not common; most x86 platforms have a signed plain `char` type) or that there are no values in the string where `word[i]` is negative (no accented characters).

For safety, therefore, the code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    table[(unsigned char)word[i]]++;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (table[(unsigned char)word[i]] > 1)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

You could use `word[i] & 0xFF` in place of the cast; it even has fewer characters, but I'd argue that the cast is clearer (and the character count is a red herring — please don't chase it).  Note that both of these variants (cast and mask) work correctly regardless of whether the plain `char` is a signed or unsigned type (though the code does make the mostly reasonable assumption that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and not some larger number — it can't be smaller).

> But why does it add to every char value it finds and not to just the one on the current position in the table? When I print out the memory location I see that from an example string `"abcda"` that both a are the same in memory. I thought in the table array they must be different (but continuous) locations; why is it the same?

When you find `'a'` in a character string, there's a byte value, usually 97, associated with that character. So when the counting code reads `word[i]` and the content of `word[i]` is `'a'`, it's as if there was 97 in the array (in fact, there is 97 in the array), so the first loop increments `table[97]` — changing it from 0 to 1 when the first `a` in `abcda` is read, and from 1 to 2 when the second `a` is read.

Characters are just numbers, when all is said and done (but there's a heck of a lot of saying and doing that can happen before all is said and done; fortunately, you don't have to go through all that most of the time).

Comment: A pet peeve: `255` is one character less than `0xff`, and has the exact same bit pattern for masking. :) For me it's on less clear, `255` is magic enough to stand out, but some people feel that bitwise things must be hex.Note that `0xff` is `int`, not unsigned (like `255` too, of course).

Comment: I guess I'm one of those "some people".  For bit masking, I seldom use decimal constants other than perhaps 1 (and I've been known to use 0x01 there when it seemed appropriate; in long lists of `#define` masks, I've used `0x00000001` when there are bits enough that some of the values are `0x40000000`). I'd not use 255 even though it requires one character less typing as it is (IMO) less explicit than 0xFF (and saving typing is not, IMO, a good metric; clarity is much more important).  YMMV, of course.

Comment: I was mainly reacting to the "it even has fewer characters" in your answer, that makes it sound like you do care. :)

Comment: It's hard to detect tongue-in-cheek ironical statements in plain text.  With or without emoji support.  :(  ☹️

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(str) {
    let result = "";
    let freq = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let char = str[i];
        let smallChar = char.toLowerCase();
        let bigChar = char.toUpperCase();
        if (freq[smallChar]) {
            freq[char]++;
        } else if (freq[bigChar]) {
            freq[char]++;
        } else {
            freq[char] = 1;
            result = result + char;
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}

removeDuplicates("ItWorks with any word");
```

Comment: The question was "can explain to me how the following works" so an answer that is purely code without comments isn't directly answering this question.